Remove "Ask Github Copilot" option from Command Palette
VS Code has a feature where any time the command palette opens, after a second or two, the text that I'm typing gets added as a suggestion for a prompt to ask Copilot.

I find this pretty annoying, and will never use it.
Is it possible to disable, without removing Copilot altogether?
(I asked Copilot, but its suggestions were not helpful.)

Hmm, I suspect the answer is, you can't: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/195023

There's a feature request to be able to disable this: Setting to turn off "Ask Github Copilot" in the command palette for arbitrary input (see image) #195023. I suggest that you give that issue ticket a thumbs up to show support for it. You can also subscribe to it to get notified about discussion and progress. Please avoid making noisy comments there like ones that just consist of "+1" / "bump". I'm not aware of any workaround.
